# Lambda expressions (how is the extension function Select defined?)

Tags: c#, extension-methods, lambda

```
var numbers=new int[]{1,2,3};
var numbers1=numbers.Select(n=>n);
var numbers2=numbers.Select(n=>n.ToString());
var numbers3=numbers.Select(n=>new {Number=n, Even=n%2==0});
```

How is it possible for the output of extension function SELECT to be of any type?

Comment: If this subject interests you, there's a video of me explaining how it works here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/11/17/a-face-made-for-email-part-three.aspx

Answer (score 5):

It is a [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) extension method defined with the following signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tresult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
                this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                Func<TSource, TResult> selector);
```

With the type information present in the source and selector argument, the compiler can infer the types used so you don't need to explicitly name it.

Comment: You forgot to include the method's return type (`IEnumerable<Tresult>`).

Answer (score 1):

The particular version of `Select` here takes a `Func<T, TResult>` selector, where `T` is the type of the input (in this case, `int`), and `TResult` is the output. Based upon your lambda expression, the compiler is able to infer the types of `TResult`. In your case, the types are

- int
- string
- Anonymous

If you are curious about such anonymous functions, I encourage to you to check out the [C# 4.0 language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029), perhaps starting at section 7.15.

Answer (score 1):

[`IEnumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) is a [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with these signatures:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector
)

public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector
)
```

The function passed in must return a `TResult` and the `Select` itself returns `IEnumerable<TResult>`. The type of `TResult` can be deduced by the compiler (as done in the post), or it can be explicitly annotated.

More information about generics -- how `TResult` can be "an arbitrary but particular type", for instance -- can be found at the [C# Generics Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). There are a number of SO questions that discuss the limits of C# type inference (including that of generics) as well.

Happy coding.